# How to find out how many figures are currently opened?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-figure

Is there a way to know how many figures are opened in matlab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
numel(get(0,'Children'));
```

You can also use what @triazotan suggested, using the **findobj** function. However it will be slower, because you need to go through all of your objects.

**Edit:**
I've decided to see how **findobj** works exactly. It is a much more complicated way of going through all of the objects in **get(0,'Children')**
Here is small digest from the file that is being called from **findobj**:
Check out the **builtin( 'get', 0, 'ShowHiddenHandles' )** which is essentially a **get(0,'Children')** in the middle:

```
function h = findobjhelper( varargin )

%Copyright 2009-2010 The MathWorks, Inc.

allowHVHandles = true;

nin = nargin;
rootHandleVis = builtin( 'get', 0, 'ShowHiddenHandles' );

% See if 'flat' keyword is present 
hasflat = false;
if (nin > 1) 
    if strcmp( varargin{2}, 'flat' ) % Does the 'flat' keyword exist
        hasflat = true;
    end
end

if nin == 0
    if feature('HgUsingMatlabClasses')
        h = findobjinternal( 0, '-function', @findobjfilter );  
    else
        h = findobjinternal(0);
    end
```

Thus, using **findobj** is clearly an overkill.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know any direct way, but you could try:

```
length(findobj('Type','figure'))
```

(i.e. count number of figure handles returned by `findobj`)